# Compare each element in a list with every element in another list

Tags: python, list, append, compare

I have two lists, `words = ["hello", "how", "hello", "are", "you"]` and `match = ["hello, "sonic"]`. How do I compare in such a way that if the first element in match is the same as the first element in words and (same for second, third etc), then append `'true'` to another list?

So for the above lists, I would want `results = ["true", "false", true", "false", "false"]`. I currently have the following but this only appends `true` and never `false`. I know that it is because the `else` statement never executes as `'hello'` is always in `words[]`. I know I am quite far off the mark here.

```
for i in match:
    if i in words:
        results.append('true')
    else:
        results.append('false')
```

I hope I explained it well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the python "in" syntax:

```
match = ["hello", "sonic"]
words = ["hello", "how", "hello", "are", "you"]
results = [w in match for w in words]
```

or if you want the strings "true" or "false"

```
results = [str(w in match).lower() for w in words]
```